# read data with different length in matlab

Tags: matlab, scanf

I have a file 'output.polygon' storing multiple rows of data which have different length, just like the following

```
7760 5593040 0 5622880 0 5591040 7760 5593040 
65000 5407200 0 5407200 0 0 65000 0 65000 5407200 
7760 5593040
```

What I'm trying to do is that first read all the data then parse it with space.

```
conductor = fopen('output.polygon');
s = fscanf(conductor, '%s');
A = strread(s);
```

However, my code doesn't work. Can anybody help me to point out the problem and give a hint on this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) function, which allows you to specify a column delimiter. The following code loads your data into a sparse matrix A:

```
 A = importdata('output.polygon',' ');

 A =

    7760     5593040           0     5622880           0     5591040        7760     5593040
   65000     5407200           0     5407200           0           0       65000           0
   65000     5407200         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
    7760     5593040         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fid = fopen('output.polygon','r');
A = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
A = A{1};
```

Answer (score 0):

so you can do this:

```
conductor = fopen('output.polygon');
A = fscanf(conductor, '%d');
```